# How to prove that I have presented a paper?

Tags: conference, presentation, certification

I am a student of English literature.

Last week I presented my paper at a conference. It was arranged by a prestigious institution. However, they did not offer any certificate or any such documentation of participation. They don't have a website or archive. However, I do have the acceptance mail. Can I use it if the institution wants to see proof of my participation?

How do I prove my participation in the conference in my future interviews? Do all the conferences offer certificates to its presenters?

I actually don't know if institutions really ask for certificates or not. That's why I asked.

Comment: I never heard of certificates being offered at conferences. Also, I don't see a reason why someone would doubt your participation, provided that you do have a paper at your hands. Doesn't the conference have an official website? A registration site, sthg? Worst comes to worst you can tell interviewers (should they ask for confirmation) to call the institution?

Comment: Aside from the issue of certificates and such, if there is a web page associated with the conference that has your name on it (better would be online abstracts of the talks, if they exist), then you may want to save it at the [internet archive](https://archive.org/web/) in case (as is likely 10 or 15 years from now) the web page winds up disappearing. And don't forget to keep the ULR you get by following the "Save Page Now" process.

Comment: Check the grammar of the last sentence, please. You are _a student of English literature_.

Comment: If an institution asks you for such a certificate, you may seriously want to reconsider if you want to join it.

Comment: I have been asked to provide certificates of participation for the refunding of conferences, and most conferences where I have been give them out, some mentioning the presentation as well. However in cases in which I didn't get a certificate I could ultimately convince the uni administration  (occasionally with a bit of effort) that my name on the conference program and the receipt for the conference fee are enough.

Comment: The institution does not have any such archive or website where they put up such information. However, I do have the acceptance mail though. Can I use it if the institution wants to see proof of my participation?

I actually don't know if institutions really asks for certificates or not. That's why I asked.

Comment: Christian Hennig: this conference did not offer any receipt as well. However, I do have the acceptance mail.

Comment: @cconsta1 Many conferences provide a certificate of attendance to the participants, and some institutions want to see them before reimbursing the expenses.

Comment: I'm talking about applying for jobs and scholarship or higher studies btw where my paper presentation is highly significant

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I see, yes that makes sense. I only participated at conferences in which I submitted an abstract in advance, so reimbursement was automatic.

Comment: @cconsta1 Having submitted an abstract doesn’t imply that one participates to a conference: for instance, without a certificate of attendance, you can submit an abstract, don’t go to the conference and get the reimbursement, thus committing fraud against the university.

Comment: Guys, what is the reimbursement you are talking about? I'm a bit confused. I was talking about applying to a university for higher studies where my paper presentation will be regarded with significant value.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, you are correct, I guess I put too much faith in people :)
@ Abdullah
Is it possible to email them back (responding to the acceptance email maybe), explain the situation, and ask for some official documentation of your participation?

Comment: @AbdullahRayhan Yes, I understand that your case is different, but I was giving a reason for conferences to give a certificate of attendance. The reimbursement is the money you get from your employing university to cover the travelling expenses to a conference.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you don't need to "prove" anything. People will believe what you say unless some red-flag appears questioning your honesty.

Surely, someone knows of your participation, the person/people who invited/accepted you. If you ever need to provide some justification, then just ask the place questioning your participation to contact the conference organizers.

If the conference publishes a proceedings in any form then you may show up there, depending on the format and the nature of your participation. Talks normally do.

You can also keep any electronic records you have, emails and such.

Comment: I do have the acceptance mail. That will work?